# block-level anchor not taking up space around text [IE7]

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I have an anchor tag with some simple CSS:

```
div {
  background-color: gray; /* for debugging */
}

div a {
  display: block;
  padding: 6px 4px 6px 7px;
  background-color: red; /* for debugging */
}
```

In Firefox, the anchor (in red) is clickable even outside of the text because of it being `display: block` with some padding. In IE7, when I hover over the red area that is not text, the anchor is no longer a link there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `zoom: 1` to the element. This gives the element [hasLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250481(VS.85).aspx), which is not only the source of 60% of all IE bugs (according to a survey I made up to make this point), but also tends to plague block-level anchors.

Comment: Thanks, I added `zoom: 1;` to the `div a` however now its appearing like its no longer block but inline. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Somehow a combination of `zoom: 1; position: relative;` seemed to have worked for me. So buggy!

Answer (score 1):

`zoom: 1` worked for me without `position: relative`, however `display: block` was set on my `a` elements.

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 nav bars on my pages at http://gvtdev.davebezaire.com. Setting `zoom:1; display:block;` caused one menu (along the left) to behave properly. The other (across the top) will not work right even when I add `position:relative; width:100%`. For now, I've set set up `a:hover {text-decoration:underline;}` and that will have to be good enough unless someone has suggestions for me.

As a fairly new web page developer, it really is disheartening to learn how much of my effort gets expended on fixes for IE!

Answer (score 0):

Use `zoom: 1 !important;` worked for me.